# A user with two accounts in the same group unable to access the site with one account

Tags: permissions, access

A user has two AD accounts, a 'user' account and a 'domain admin' account. He is in a SharePoint group that has contribute access to the sub-site. There's a document library in the sub-site which inherits permissions. When the user tries to access with his domain admin account, he gets an access denied error, the domain user can edit documents. Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'access with his domain account?' - is he getting the error viewing the list?  Viewing the document properties or opening the document itself in the native application?  Does he get an access denied error if he merely tries to save the document rather than open it?

Comment: What content/area is the domain admin account trying to access? Is it the document library? Is your domain user a site collection admin/farm admin? What role does domain admin has in SharePoint site? Pls elaborate to make things clear.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "He is in a SharePoint group" is both accounts in there? What does "Check Effective Permissions" report on the two accounts?

Comment: Thanks to all for asking the correct questions, some which I asked myself. Let me clarify this was nothing specific with doc library, it was just the access to the site was being denied. This user (who was added by the admin) had accounts in multiple domains, and the account from the correct domain was not added. From the UI, just by looking at the login name it was not apparent that the nameswer from diff domains, until I executed a script to get the "GetUserEffectivePermissions". Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Double the way you give permission in your site collection. 
When you say he is in a SharePoint Group , how you grant the permission?
Do you add the domain user directly to the SharePoint Member Group or do you add a AD group to the SharePoint Member  Group. 
If his domain admin account does not have access , can you add his domain admin account to the SharePoint Member Group?